# How to remove black water stains from maple

Tags: stain-removal

I have black water stains on clear maple window sills. I have tried multiple applications of wood bleach after I removed the finish. The stains are much lighter but darken up when I wipe with a wet sponge.
I plan to remove all of the finish and add no stain and coat with a couple of coats of polyurethane.

Is there anything I can do to lighten up the stains completely?

If not, is there a sealer that will prevent the stain from darkening when the poly is applied?

Comment: There different kinds of wood bleach, have you tried Oxalic acid?

Comment: You may find more knowledge over at https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The depth of the stain may be the issue here , if you can post a clear in focus photo we may be able to provide additional advice. If the finish is removed oxalic acid may help but use caution with this and any other wood bleach sometimes sanding through the stain may be needed to eliminate it completely.